# How to edit a file and pass values into it through Puppet

Tags: linux, puppet

I want to pass limit values in /etc/security/limits.conf in all servers available in environment through puppet. Need to be automated this process whenever i create new instance, this limit values directly append to new boxes

Answer (score 1):

There's an official [puppet module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/limits) for modifying limits.

You could also use [file_line](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib#resources) for this.

```
file_line { 'append_limits_conf':
  path => '/etc/security/limits.conf',
  match => 'variable_name',
  line => 'vriable_name = foobar',
}
```

The `match` will be used to determine if the variable is already declared within the file. If yes - it will change the value to whatever you define at `line`. If it's not in there it will just append the line.

More sophisticated file editing can be done with [augeas](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#augeas) - but might be overkill for you case right now.